# Cant find faster way to read Excel file with multiple sheets using office interop (i know about many topics)

Tags: excel, vb.net, range

I know about many topics with similar issues, but cant find anything to help me solve slow reading of the excel (xslx) file. I don't know, it is normal with this code 1 minutes 20 seconds  for 20 sheets ("sheet1" 80 rows 33 columns to read, other sheets from 2 to 10 rows and 33 columns). Application reads first sheet  about 25 sec and rest of time all other sheets. it is only test file, normal ones will be 50 sheets. Rows quantity in the first sheet also rises. 
I did same code with ranges, but this did not helped me make it a lot faster, but it was harder to understand which cell i really read.
Here is how i made reading:

```
Private Sub GetAsiigmentsFullData(ByRef ProjectOperationsAssigment As AssigmentData, ByVal ExcelFilePath As String)
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBok As Excel.Workbook
Dim sapp As String
Dim SpecialSheetName As String = "export"
Dim ExceptionalSheetName As String = "Data check"
Dim newproduct As Product
Dim HeadersRowNum = CInt(modINI.ReadIni(IniAssigments, "ExcellInfo", "ColumHeaders", "3"))
Dim ExcellCachedAsOpen As Boolean = False
Try
            xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
            ExcellCachedAsOpen = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        End Try

Dim ExcelfileName As String = ExcelFilePath
        If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
            xlApp.Visible = False
            xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
            xlBok = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelfileName)
        Else
            MsgBox("Excel book: " & ExcelfileName & " Open error")
        End If

        xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim lsheets As Object
        If Not xlBok Is Nothing Then
            xlBok.Activate()
            lsheets = xlBok.Worksheets
        Else
            MsgBox("Excell file read error")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim SheetCount As Integer = 0
        TxtBox_StatusBar.Text = "Sheets read: " & SheetCount.ToString & "/" & CStr(xlBok.Worksheets.Count)

        If Not lsheets Is Nothing Then

            For Each ls As Excel.Worksheet In lsheets
                SheetCount += 1
                TxtBox_StatusBar.Text = "Sheets read: " & SheetCount.ToString & "/" & CStr(xlBok.Worksheets.Count)
                If ls.Name = SpecialSheetName Then ProjectOperationsAssigment.projectCode = ls.Cells(1, 1).value
                If ls.Name = ExceptionalSheetName Then Continue For
                If Not ls Is Nothing Then
                    For Each oAssigment As Assignment In ProjectOperationsAssigment.oneAssignment
                        Dim clmIndex As Integer = getColumnIndex(ls, oAssigment.PropName, HeadersRowNum)
                        Dim emptyCellsInAColumns As Integer = 0
                        Dim beforWasEmpty As Boolean = False
                        Dim i As Integer = 3

                        Do Until emptyCellsInAColumns = 3
                            i += 1

                            If ls.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then

                                If ls.Cells(i, clmIndex).Value <> "" AndAlso ls.Cells(HeadersRowNum, clmIndex).Value = ls.Cells(i, clmIndex).Value Then
                                    newproduct = New Product
                                    For Each cr In newproduct.CriteriaList
                                        Dim j As Integer = 1

                                        Do While ls.Cells(HeadersRowNum - 1, j).Value <> "OPR"

                                            If ls.Cells(HeadersRowNum, j).Value = cr.CrPropName Then
                                                cr.crPropValue = ls.Cells(i, j).Value
                                                Exit Do
                                            End If


                                            j += 1
                                        Loop
                                    Next
                                    oAssigment.ProductList.Add(newproduct)

                                End If
                                beforWasEmpty = False
                            ElseIf beforWasEmpty = True AndAlso ls.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                                emptyCellsInAColumns += 1
                                beforWasEmpty = True
                            ElseIf beforWasEmpty = False AndAlso ls.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                                emptyCellsInAColumns = 1
                                beforWasEmpty = True
                            End If

                        Loop
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If


        xlBok.Close()
        If Not ExcellCachedAsOpen Or xlApp.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(lsheets)
        releaseObject(xlBok)
        releaseObject(xlApp)

        GC.Collect()

    End Sub
```

About data in excel file:
all sheets using 33 columns. Row 3 is headers, in row 2 is data which representing type of data under header.
Need to read all sheets and store it in one structured class.

i will be very thankful for any useful suggestions how to make read from excel faster.

Comment: A faster way would be to not use the interop, there's a lof of library that can do the job much faster.

Comment: And if there no ways use other library? or at least hard to do that?

Comment: Start by adding `Option Strict On` to the top of the code file; this will force you to think about your data and use proper conversions instead of asking the compiler/runtime to make its best guess (implicit conversions are slow). Declare `lsheets` as an Excel.Sheets.  Do not treat every cell value as a `String`. The `Range.Value` property returns type `Object` and that Object can hold: 1) Nothing (null), 2) a String, a Double, or 3) a DateTime.  Try reading the rectangular data region as a two dimensional array of Objects and process that array instead of reading each cell individually.

Comment: Sounds like the teacher scold me for the bad behavior. But knowing myself as not very experienced coder, this is normal. I tried most of this what is written. Seems it helped me more than i have expected.

Realy thank you

Comment: if all of your sheets arranged as tables, the fastest way will be to open excel using `Interop.Excel`--> deleting empty rows in each sheet in order for the tables to start in row 1 than saving and closing the file and than query with sql steatments each sheet using `OleDb`. store all data inside dataset, datatable for each sheet.